# How to fine tune ELK

Tags: elastic-stack

We are running out of heap memory and also unstability issues in our ELK, below the configuration screenshot.

-Version 6.2.4
-No of nodes: 5
-Data nodes: 3
-Indices: 6138
-Documents: 3,840,550,046
-Primary shards: 14,934
-Replica Shards: 14,934
-Disk Available: 25.98(1TB/5TB)
-JVM Heap: 62.045(46GB/74GB)

I am know that I have to reduce on number of shards and also data we are holding is since Jan 2019-although 2019 data is in closed state.

I need help on understanding as how can I do
1- re-indexing to reduce the number of shards of the old indices
2- download of old indices and keep in a archive and later re-use the same if and when required
3- we are having daily indices rotation, how to change it to weekly/monthly indices and how it will help.

Looking forward for some guidance as ELK is new to me and am held up with this.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: this is not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1- re-indexing to reduce the number of shards of the old indices

A reindex is rather expensive; if you have more than one primary shard per index (on 6.x the default was 5), I'd start with a [`_shrink`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-shrink-index.html), which is much cheaper.

> 2- download of old indices and keep in a archive and later re-use the same if and when required

Sounds like [snapshot and restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-snapshots.html), but that will be a slow and tedious approach.

> 3- we are having daily indices rotation, how to change it to weekly/monthly indices and how it will help.

The better approach would be a [rollover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-rollover-index.html) that offers more flexibility and also allows you to create evenly sized indices / shards. Our default for the Beats in 7.x is 50GB for a single shard index.

Generally your Elasticsearch version is very old. There are a lot of performance and stability improvements in the current 7.10 version. Also features like [Index Lifecycle Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/overview-index-lifecycle-management.html), which would be the solution for your kind of problem.

Some additional notes:

- Why are only 3 of 5 nodes data nodes?
- As you said, the number of indices and shards is way too high.
- The heap size should only go up to ~30GB, so that Java can use compressed pointers.

Comment: 3 of 5 are as data nodes because of resource constraint, on the other 2 elastic servers, we are running kibana, also, currently our elastic is on 20gb min max heap

Comment: Good on the heap. In the end that is probably just not enough hardware, especially for the number of shards. Get to a current version of Elasticsearch (and Java), reduce the number of shards, and then see if it's workable.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer :)